# How can I filter array values in a Json in Sql Server

Tags: json, sql-server

How can I filter an array value without specifying the index in the array

This is my array

```
{   
   "level1":{
      "level2":[
         {
            "level3":"test",            
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to retrive all rows that contains a level3 a value test.
Something like this

```
select * from Documents 
where Json_Value(DocumentInfo, '$.level1.level2[X].level3') = 'test'
```

It this not possible in Sql Server?

Comment: You can, you have to build a structurre using WITH so you can easily select from see this article https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/11/01/reading-json-string-with-nested-elements-sql-server-2016-part-3/

Comment: theres also syntax for using json_value in that article too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing of bit here, but use an `EXISTS`? This also assumes the JSON is valid, as the JSON in your question is not:

```sql
SELECT * --Should be a distinct column list
FROM dbo.Documents D
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OPENJSON(D.DocumentInfo) 
                   WITH (level1 nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) L1
                   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(L1.Level1)
                               WITH(level2 nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) L2
                   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(L2.Level2)
                               WITH (level3 varchar(10)) L3
              WHERE L3.level3 = 'test');
```